# How to pass component's state to the navigationOptions in react native (react navigation)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass a state to the top bar inside react native navigation.

Here is how my component looks:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {  
        value: ""
    };
  }

    static navigationOptions = {

    tabBarLabel: () => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
{this.state.value}
        </Text> 
        </View>
    ),  
  };
}
```

I am receiving an error `Type Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` on line {this.state.value}. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is one of the pain points of `react-navigation`. The `static` keyword indicates that this object is a part of the class `Main`, but does not require an *instance* of the class to run. So you could invoke it like so:

```
Main.navigationOptions.tabBarLabel()
```

This means that you can't refer to component state from functions declared as properties of the `navigationOptions` object. What you can do is call `navigation.setParams({ foo: ... })` from, say, `componentDidMount` or other lifecycle functions if you need to alter a title or label from within the component.

I try to steer clear of this kind of update as much as possible, as it can appear somewhat slow to the user if the value isn't defined before the component mounts.

Comment: Would it work if I set up a variable with a state inside the component and pass it to the static function instead?

Comment: I've honestly not tried calling `navigationOptions` functions directly. I 
 don't think it will work though, because `react-navigation` uses these functions/values internally to set screen properties.

Comment: I am doing something like this now: ```static navigationOptions = ({ navigation}) => ({
    tabBarLabel: () => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
        {navigation.state.params.name}
        </Text> 
        </View>
    ),  
    
  });     

componentDidMount(){
        navigation.setParams({ name: "Heloo" });
    }``` 
but it gives me similar error. I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does it say is undefined? You should provide a default value, as that function may get called prior to `componentDidMount`. So `{navigation.state.params.name || 'Foo'}`, for example.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The error is ```Cannot read property of 'name' of undefined.```

Comment: You'll probably need to test for the existence of the property first before attempting to use it. `navigation` doesn't *always* have `state.params`, so you might need to do `if (navigation.state.params)` or similar.

Comment: You can also I believe pass a default value from the screen definition, which could be overridden... you'd need to check the docs on that one.